# How do I disable locator maps?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I am playing on a world, and my friend is threatening to use locator maps to find and grief my base. How could I disable them using commands? (By the way, by disable I mean make them unusable.)

Answer (score -1):

Use an Always Active Repeating Command Block and use `/clear` to that player, but it has to be a specific item.

```
/clear <player> map
```

Removes all their maps, locator or not, but not empty ones. If you want, you can remove `empty_map`s instead.